# Supporting Range requests in a netty HTTP server

Tags: http, netty

Is it possible to construct a pipeline which supports [Range requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35)? Alternatively, can someone point me at the parts of the API that I should look at if I wanted to implement such support myself?

(Motivated by https://github.com/webbit/webbit/issues/49)

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible but I think you will have to respond to the headers directly and construct  your response accordingly.

The Netty examples dealing with serving files should help.

In act I think the default is to send the whole file as a 'range' but you could construct your own range and then it will be sent as a chunked reply

Comment: I think this functionality should live within Netty, similar to the existing http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpContentCompressor.html. I'll raise an issue and hopefully come up with tests and a patch.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at our open source library SIRIUS which provides a thin layer above netty. We implemented support for range requests in our send file method:

https://github.com/scireum/sirius/blob/develop/web/src/sirius/web/http/Response.java#L504

Our tool "S3Ninja" (http://s3ninja.net - MIT licensed) which emulates the S3 API successfully delivers videos to iPhone/iPad devices which for example require support for range requests.

Feel free to use SIRIUS (http://sirius-lib.net) in your own product (MIT licensed) or get inspired by the code, it's not that difficult to do.